# JavaFX - How to synchronize CustomTab (extending Tab) and TabPane

Tags: java, javafx, tabs, synchronization, tabpanel

I am developing an IDE. I created a `CustomTab.java` class by extending the default JavaFX `Tab`. I wanted to add a color transition animation, but I ran into a problem. The method in `TabPane` named `getTabs()`, which returns `ObservableList<Tab>`, is final. This means I can't override it to return `ObservableList<CustomTab>`. It seems that constructions like this:

```
for (Tab tab : tabPane.getTabs()) {
    ((CustomTab) tab).stopFlash();
}
```

used in `Controller.java` are neck breaking and wrong.
What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Thank you for edit that post. As you can see my english is bad, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I think my reply is quiete late, but I think there is a way to do so. 
Use the function

```
tab.setUserData(Object c);
```

In that Object you can store all the informations you'll need to proceed.

so for example create an Object holding all the objects you need. 
E.g. you can hold the reference to your webView.

Also if you need to have different informations you could use:

```
tab.getProperties().put(Object key, Object data);
// receive the value with 
tab.getProperties().get(key);
```

[Here a link to the documentation I found](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/javafx/scene/control/Tab.java#Tab.setUserData%28java.lang.Object%29)

Maybe the Javadoc is better, but I found this one.

Here is a little example that I wrote:

```
public SQLEditorTab getNewTab(){
    SQLEditorTab tab = new SQLEditorTab("new Tab " + number);
    tab.setId("newTab" + number);
    tab.setOnCloseRequest(this);
    tab.setUserData(tab.tabContent);
    number ++; 
    return tab;
} // just to create the tab
```

In my listener I receive the result simply by:

```
    sqlEditorPane.getTabs().forEach((Tab t) -> {
        if(t.getUserData() != null){
            System.out.print(t.getUserData().getClass());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Saved me a lot of time. Thanks!